# +MySQL Query for finding ids against which the columns are a subset of an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing a basic portfolio website on Laravel.

A feature that I have there is that there is a section "Jobs for me" which automatically fetches jobs posted on my website which are relevant to your skills.

The way I do this is: I query the Skills table first. Its schema is: (userid,name,value) where name is the name of the skill and value is the value of the skill (0-100). The way the querying works is that I fetch the authorised user's id using Auth::id() and then query the Skills table
for:

```
select name where userid = Auth::id()
```

Then, I iterate over the skills fetched and push them into an array.

Finally, I have a JobSkills table whose schema is (jobid,name,value).

This is where the issue is. How do I query this table such that all jobids against whom names (skill's name) are a subset of the skills in the array are fetched.

My current strategy for the whole thing (including a query that I have tried for querying the JobSkills table) currently is:

```
$id = \Auth::id();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $skills = Skill::where('userid',$id)->get();
    $skillsArr = [];
    foreach($skills as $skill){
        $skillsArr[] = $skill->name;
    }


    
    $jobs = $jobs = JobSkill::select('jobid')
    ->whereIn('name', $skillsArr)
    ->groupBy('jobid')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT name) = ?', [count($skillsArr)])
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name NOT IN (?) THEN name END) = 0', [$skillsArr])
    ->get();
```

Edit for adding more context:

UserSkills table:[image: UserSkills table:]

Jobs table:[image: Jobs table:]

JobSkills table:[image: JobSkills table:]

What I want to do is: find all the Job IDs whose skills are a subset of the skills of a particular user.

Comment: Could you add a simple data set with what you want, vs what you currently have?  Cross-referencing tables should be taken care of in the database (via query language), and not rely on storing anything in the code.  Ex. a join.  But we can't give a viable solution without your table structure and sample data.  Do you have control over the database structure or is it fixed already?

Comment: @Nic3500 Hey, thanks for your reply. I am not quiet sure what you mean, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The database engine is built and optimised to perform queries on tables.  Instead of running one query to get the skills, then another query to see which jobs have these skills, you can perform it all in the database.  It will offload your application and use the database to its full potential.  Query language can be quite powerful.  But to suggest anything useful, we need to see your database tables structure (primary keys, foreign keys, ...) and a sample of data.  This looks like a JOIN in a query with some WHERE clause(s).

Comment: Sidenote, but all of that `$skillsArr = []; foreach(...)` can be replaced with a single line: `$skillsArr = Skill::where('userid', $id)->pluck('name');`, which returns a `Collection` of `name` columns that match. If you need an Array, tack on `->toArray()` after `->pluck()`.

Comment: For more context, the ID in Jobs table is the the Job ID and the userid is the id of the user who posted / created the job. The jobid in the JobSkills table is the ID of the job ( the id column in the Jobs table ). Hopefully, that adds further context.

Comment: @Nic3500 Hey, I added some stuff that you requested for context.

Comment: Have look at this: https://phpize.online/s/vC it is an illustration of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **using your tables and some assumed data**. *NOTE:* Images of data are as useless to us as images of puppies using laptops. Instead copy/paste "data" as tables so it can be re-used.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell This should be an answer.  And thank you for that phpize site, I love it.